# Calculating Statistical summary in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I run the following query the get the average likes for each Category

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ START n=node:node_auto_index(type = "U") match n-[r:likes]->()-[:mapsTo]->items return AVG(r.count) as AVGLIKES, items.name as CATEGORY;
==> +------------------------------------------------------+
==> | AVGLIKES           | CATEGORY                        |
==> +------------------------------------------------------+
==> | 7.122950819672131  | "Culture"                       |
==> | 1.3333333333333333 | "Food & Drinks"                 |
==> | 2.111111111111111  | "Albums"                        |
==> | 2.581081081081081  | "Movies"                        |
==> | 2.1                | "Musicians"                     |
==> | 7.810126582278481  | "Culture Celebs"                |
==> | 3.1206896551724137 | "TV Shows"                      |
==> | 1.0                | "Apps/Games"                    |
==> | 4.0256410256410255 | "Cars"                          |
```

But AVG is a built in function, how do I calculate the standard deviation and other statistical summaries for each category. I am looking for something like *"GROUP BY"* in  SQL that will group everything for each category and then I could write some code or if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I added the percentile_disc, percentile_cont aggregation functions late last year. I imagine they would be willing to merge in functions for std dev. In theory (I think, my statistics is rusty) you could calculate the standard deviation based on some samples of percentiles along with the average. So, aside from standard deviation, what else are you looking for?

Update:
I made a pull request for stdev/stdevp aggregation functions: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/859

Comment: Range and median are essential. How can I do this myself though. for example sd= sqrt( sum(x-mean(x))^2/(n-1) ). The problem is if I use collect, I still need to have the mean(x), so I ma not sure how to do this

Comment: median is the same as percentile_disc(x, .5), and range is max(x) and min(x). You can simulate mean over a collection using reduce like so: reduce(total=0, x in coll: total+x)/length(coll).

Comment: Thank you very much, how do I update my neo4j with the changes you made?